# How to send frames for MediaCodec for recording in ARCore app?

Tags: encoding, android-mediacodec, arcore

Based on the sample code in `computervision` package in arcore I am trying to send the frame retrieved in `onDrawFrame` to MediaCodec input surface but when I call `lockCanvas()` on the input surface attached to the MediaCodec the app crashes. It did work for me when working directly with camera without ARcore.
What is the correct way to send frames to video encoder (hardware accelerated) from ARcore app?

Comment: I just posted an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869061/providing-video-recording-functionality-with-arcore for creating a video of the surface.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I needed! And it worked (on Pixel)