# How to record video with ARCore with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I have been stuck on this problem for over a month now. I just need to record the video feed when people are using the AR app.

There are several options:

**1. Take the screenshot in Unity for every frame.**

I tried [taking a screenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html) every frame. This is way too slow. The fps is only 5.
Then I tried [saving the texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture.html) to an array and encode them to images afterwards. 
This would take a lot of memory and would cause a significant frame drop on mobile phone. The fps is around 10.

If anyone has a great idea for this method, please let me know.

**2. Use native plugins to record video.**

I haven't found any solutions on this one. I am afraid that this may conflict with the ARCore.

I know that there is an [Android solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869061/providing-video-recording-functionality-with-arcore) but ideally I want to use Unity. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**3. Save the texture from the texture reader api provided by ARCore computer vision example.**

There is a Computer Vision example in the directory. And I can get the texture directly from GPU with its api.

However, the fps is still low. With its edge detector example, the fps is around 15. I succeeded in saving those frames to local directory in another thread. But the fps is still not acceptable. The bottomline is 720p at 30fps.

PS: I just need to save the frames. I can handle encoding them into videos.

PPS: **Just recording the camera feed** and **recording the camera feed and the augmented objects together** are both okay. Either one achieved is great.

Comment: Nicely asked. Welcome to StackOverflow mate!

Comment: @RannLifshitz Thanks for the editing bro!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily implement video recording AND sharing using the (really great) [NatCorder unity asset](https://medium.com/@olokobayusuf/natcorder-unity-recording-made-easy-f0fdee0b5055) ([asset store link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/natcorder-video-recording-api-102645)) and the related [NatShare API](https://medium.com/@olokobayusuf/natshare-api-easy-free-sharing-db1019f290bc). I did this very same thing in my own [ARCore experiment/"game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NoahAR.PaintAR&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackoverflow%26utm_medium%3Danswer%26utm_campaign%3Dquestion49952116)."

Edit: you may have to implement [this](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/141) workaround to get a smooth framerate.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried your app and the recording  is quite nice! I will try to use it in my project.

Comment: Great! Any upvotes / marking my message as an answer would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Nerk, I implemented NatCorder in my own app and can only get 5 fps when recording with a virtual 3d object and 10 fps when only camera view is active. What workaround exactly did you used to achieve a smooth framerate? I checked your link but I am not even hitting 30fps so I don't think that the solution would help me.

Comment: @ZeroLu https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/141 see pablishos first comment

Comment: @ZeroLu if you are getting those framerates you likely have other issues. i imagine the framerate is low without natcorder.

Comment: the fps is 20fps and 10fps without natcorder. I tried HelloAR with natcorder's ReplayCam.cs and can get 20fps(MatchFramerate disabled). But your PaintAR video is 30fps. How is this possible? Did you use Replay API or NatCorder API?

Comment: I used the Replay API and the NatShare API. Your main FPS is not because of NatCorder/Replay API it seems. 10-20fps without NatCorder implemented is quite low. @ZeroLu

Comment: I am happy to say that I finally achieved 30fps with NatCorder API. Some info can be seen here(https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/221). I am probably going to write a blogpost on this topic.

Comment: @nerk how to record the game camera in natcorder? there is no tutorial available for this

Comment: @Soorya this should get you started: https://medium.com/@olokobayusuf/natcorder-unity-recording-made-easy-f0fdee0b5055