# how to record a video by unity arcore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

How to record video with unity arcore?
I found some answers, but this plugin can't record the AR model.
I want to know how to do it.

[How to record video with ARCore with Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952116/how-to-record-video-with-arcore-with-unity)

Comment: Could you precise why you need the video?

Comment: I am developing a feature where the user takes a picture or records a video of the model in the AR scene and then shares it.