# How to capture Camera footage /capture using ARCore

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am very new to ARCore...
Trying to capture camera footage of ARCore and proceass the video/still picture of it.

Does anyone have any example on how to capture camera footage of android phone using ARCore? ( Either In form of Video or Still picture)

I would like to take this footage as part of the app not for marketing purposes.

does anyone know which ARCore API to use?

Appreciate your help ...

Comment: https://www.andreasjakl.com/how-to-record-a-video-from-a-unity-arcore-app-on-android/

Comment: Found this and it's working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191513/how-to-take-picture-with-camera-using-arcore

Comment: I am pretty sure what your asking is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869061/providing-video-recording-functionality-with-arcore

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery) to capture a photo of the screen very easily like this:

```
StartCoroutine( TakeScreenshotAndSave() );
```

This is one of their examples on how to capture and save it to gallery

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshotAndSave()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D ss = new Texture2D( Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
    ss.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height ), 0, 0 );
    ss.Apply();

    // Save the screenshot to Gallery/Photos
    Debug.Log( "Permission result: " + NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery( ss, "GalleryTest", "My img {0}.png" ) );

    // To avoid memory leaks
    Destroy( ss );
}
```